# Hide layer groups in a workspace from getCapabilities

Tags: geoserver

I am working with GeoServer Version 2.10.3, I hide layers from getCapabilities - I
set the layer as not advertised.

Is it posible to 'hide' layer group from getCapabilities?

The layers in the layer group are marked as not advertised but I can still see the group in the getCapabilities

Note: layers from a group should be visible on the map

Comment: I would read the documentation about the layer group modes https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/webadmin/layergroups.html#layer-group-modes and consider if some of the supported modes feels right.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the handling of layer groups has changed in the last 13 versions, so upgrading to 2.23.2 would be a good first step